# Displaying json object details in knockout js

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, knockout.js

I have the following fiddle where I am trying to display the data in key:value pairs,
i.e., key as header and followed by the information as rows .

I have the data in this format:

```
 self.data = ko.observableArray([{
        1:
        {

            name: 'Name 1',
            lastLogin: '8/5/2012'

        }
        }
    , {
         2:
         {
            name: 'Name 2',
            lastLogin: '2/8/2013'
        }
    }

    ]);
```

I have fiddle as :

```
https://jsfiddle.net/1988/z7nnf0fh/1/
```

I am expecting as:

```
1

name    Name 1  lastLogin   8/5/2012

2
name    Name 2  lastLogin   2/8/2013
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd personally move all logic to your viewmodel. Then you could either use ko.toJSON to stringify the contents of each object or if you really want to have the output like above, you could do:

```js
function DataModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.data = ko.observableArray([{
      1: {

        name: 'Name 1',
        lastLogin: '8/5/2012'

      }
    }, {
      2: {
        name: 'Name 2',
        lastLogin: '2/8/2013'
      }
    }

  ]);
  self.formattedValues = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.formatData = function() {
    var tempRow = [];
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.data(), function(item) {
      for (var i in item) {
        for (var j in item[i]) {
          tempRow.push({
            key: j,
            value: item[i][j]
          });
        }
        self.formattedValues.push({
          key: i,
          rows: tempRow
        });
        tempRow = [];
      }
    })
  };
  self.formatData();
}

var dataModel = new DataModel();
ko.applyBindings(dataModel);
```

```css
.name {
  color: #bbb;
}
.value {
  fot-weight: bold
}
th {
  width: 25px;
}
p {
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div data-bind="template: { name: 'template', data: formattedValues }"></div>

<script type="text/html" id="template">
  <table>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: $data">
      <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: key"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td data-bind="foreach: rows">
          <p>
            <span class="name" data-bind="text: key + ': '"></span>
            <span class="value" data-bind="text: value"></span>
          </p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</script>
```

Hope that helps in some way